# How to dynamically add and bind a widget using javascript in maximo anywhere

Tags: charts, widget, maximo-anywhere

I am using maximo anywhere 7.5.2. I am new to this technology. My reqiuerment is, from the new view have to display a pie chart/ bar chart based on the some dynamic data. as a report. I don't know how to show display a chart as a widget dynamically. Please anyone have idea on this ,kindly help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should attach a Handler to the "show" event of your View where you want to show the chart, and then programmatically instantiate and populate the chart.  For an example of a "show" handler, take a look at the app.xml pointing to "initNewWorkLogEntry" of the WorkLogHandler.js